# Publishing to the wall without user authorization

Tags: facebook-graph-api, token

I have a site and a facebook page. How can I make it so that upon addition of a new article, the user publised the required text on the page's wall under administrator's identity (i.e. my identity); without user's authorization. Is it possible to get an access_token using my login and password?

Comment: You should at least attempt to translate your question to English if you'd like to get help. Even a google translate would work. Generally, other users will edit for grammar; it's unlikely, though, that someone would translate your question manually.

Comment: Excuse me please:! I had not thought

Comment: possible duplicate of [facebook oauth username and password authentication](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5970237/facebook-oauth-username-and-password-authentication)